# android firebase database save data for current user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an app that send sms templates with firebase user login.
I want to save sms logs for each user on firbase database so I will be able to see what messages each user sent. I have no idea how to make it probably ..

my code

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar spinner;

EditText EMAIL, PASSWORD;
Button SIGNIN;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    EMAIL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    PASSWORD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    SIGNIN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    SIGNIN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL.getText().toString())) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD.getText().toString()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "make sure that you enter full ogin info ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (!isEmailValid(EMAIL.getText().toString())){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter a valid mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    SignIn(EMAIL.getText().toString(), PASSWORD.getText().toString());
                }

            }
        });
    SIGNIN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String pass = PASSWORD.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
                PASSWORD.setError("kindly enter password ");
                return;
            }





            if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(EMAIL.getText().toString())) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(PASSWORD.getText().toString()))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SignIn(EMAIL.getText().toString(), PASSWORD.getText().toString());
            }

        }
    });


    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);


}


private void SignIn(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login done",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error username",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }

                }
            });
}

public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
}
```

sms.java

```
public class Harsh extends AppCompatActivity {
RadioButton lo, hi, mid;
String sense;
Button submit;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.harsh_layout);
    lo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lo_btn);
    hi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hi_btn);
    mid = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.mid_btn);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String num = prefs.getString("nameKey", "0");

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (lo.isChecked()) {
                sendSMS( num, "  message one");

            } else if (hi.isChecked()) {
               sendSMS( num, "  message 2");
            // for example save this message for current logged user
            } else if (mid.isChecked()) {


              sendSMS( num, "  message 3");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Command Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // print the value of selected super star
        }
    });



}
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg) {
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Command Sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: None of your code interacts with the Firebase Database yet. I recommend that you start by reading the [Firebase documentation for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/). If you're more do-oriented, I recommend the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). Both of these will give you enough to at least get started on the feature. If you get stuck, post the [**minimal** code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll be better able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after alot of researches i found that set and get class and i modify my code as below

```
public class Post {

private String message;
private String number;
private String user;
private String date;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

then in activity that i need to Post data to firbase database i add that simple code

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                DatabaseReference posts = database.getReference("Messages:");
  //this code for keep posts even app offline until the app online again
                posts.keepSynced(true);

                Post post = new Post();
                post.setMessage("Messsage");
                post.setUser(name);
                post.setNumber(num);
                post.setDate(s);

                posts.push().setValue(post);
```